# Android market not showing my published apps? What to change in my app manifest to help filtering?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I recently published my Android app to the market and everything seemed fine.

I tried to download it on a particular phone (Samsung epic 4g (SPH-D700)) and it was not available. It looks like it is being filtered, along with most the other Samsung galaxy s phones.

Should I change something in my manifest so it doesn't become filtered?

Im also trying to search for it on my computer and it doesnt even show up when i do that. Does this mean it didnt actually upload it to the market?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="send.text.fast"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"> </uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"> </uses-permission>
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
  <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"> 
</supports-screens> 
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:screenOrientation="portrait">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Any ideas? i would really appreciate any help? if it means anything it has a hardware keyboard, do i have to declare that in the manifest or anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm having the same problem too. the Market (now goes by a different name) has this recently new (long awaited, they claim) feature to filter out apps that are not compatible with your device.

did you try setting minSdkVersion to your phone's particular version? try lowering it. one thing i did not know is that you can set minSdkVersion down but still target a higher version.

my app works on my android phone upon side-loading. but since i've published my app, i still can't find it on my phone when using the Market app. when i go to my app's webpage, i get a little message saying this app is not compatible with your device, which is wrong. of course, my phone has been rooted among other things (i.e. non-stock kernel/roms/launchers/etc...).

the joy of fragmentation.

Comment: Thanks for the help. yes the mim sdk version is lower than my phones verson. you said that you could set minSdkVersion down but still target a higher version(whick i didnt know either), what would change by me targeting a highet/lower version?

Comment: i think you target should be the maxSdkVersion (so to speak) because it sets the Android sdk version against which you will be using. if your minSdK version is lower than your phone and the market is still filtering, then something funny is going on. one of us should email tech support to google or someone from android should kindly clarify as you are not the only one facing this problem.